# Extracting signatures from .pk8 and .pem files ( android signature issue )

Tags: android, signature

I am trying to debug an android  TV application, for that i need to replace original system file with the edited version of the same system file

```
Issue is
```

when i tried to replace it there were signature issues, when we use android phone, i cater this issue mostly by deleting the previous file and installing the updated android apk. but in this case i cannot delete the file as it is a android's system file. thus i asked the manufacturers to provide me with the signatures of the installed system file so that i can replace it

```
My question is
```

the manufacturer has provided me with the sign apk.jar file and a .pk8 file and a .pem file. i searched the net and found that .pk8 and .pem files are used for the signatures. so how can i extract the signatures from these two files. i did not get any useful information out of internet for it.

Answer (score 2):

Extracting signature is not required, You can directly sign you unsigned apk with these 2 files. Download the "signapk.jar" from net and reun the following command:

java -jar SignApk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 application.apk application_signed.apk

**Here:**

- paltform.x509.pem should be your pem file.
- platform.pk8 should be    your pk8 file
- application.apk is your unsigned apk which can be created through
  eclipse.
- and application_signed.apk which will be    created after running
  this command.

Comment: From where do we get the .pk8 and .pem files ? I have an iBall tablet.Will I get these files by searching the tablet OS files?